# Scala dispatch GET request, fail to parse response to json

Tags: json, scala, parsing, scala-dispatch, databinder

im writing a function that :

1) send HTTP GET request (response is a valid JSON)

2) parse the response to a json object

code snippet  :

```
val page = url("http://graph.facebook.com/9098498615")
val response = Http(page OK dispatch.as.String)
Await.result(response , 10 seconds)
val myJson= JSON.parseFull(response .toString)
//this isnt helping -> val myJson= JSON.parseRaw(response .toString)
```

Problem is after this **myJson** is **None** while im expecting it to hold the json data from the response.

Help ?

Comment: no error .. just that myJson is None and not the json response im expecting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use `Http(page OK as.String)` because  all responses different from HTTP 200 will result in failed Futures. If you need more fine grained control over error handling/reporting, target specific scenarios instead.

```
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.{ HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpResponseStatus }
def getFacebookGraphData: Either[Exception, String] = {
  val page = url("http://graph.facebook.com/9098498615")
  val request = Http(page.GET);
  val response = Await.result(request, 10 seconds);
  (response.getStatusCode: @annotation.switch) match {
    case HttpResponseStatus.OK => {
      val body = response.getResponseBody() // dispatch adds this method
      // if it's not available, then:
      val body = new String(response.getContent.array);
      Right(body)
    }
    // If something went wrong, you now have an exception with a message.
    case _ => Left(new Exception(new String(response.getContent.array)));
  }
}
```

The default Scala JSON library is not a very good idea either, it's very rough compared to others. Try `lift-json` for instance.

```
import net.liftweb.json.{ JSONParser, MappingException, ParseException };

case class FacebookGraphResponse(name: String, id: String);// etc
implicit val formats = net.liftweb.DefaultFormats;
val graphResponse = JSONParser.parse(body).extract[FacebookGraphResponse];
// or the better thing, you can catch Mapping and ParseExceptions.
```

Comment: It's not really true that `OK` means "neglecting" all non-200 responses—it returns a `Future` that will fail on those responses, but that's often exactly what you want. You can still process non-200 responses cleanly.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I've added my own answer using Dispatch's "built-in" (as a sub-project) JSON support.

Answer (score 16):

Dispatch includes some really nice (and under-advertised) [facilities for parsing JSON](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/tree/master/json4snative), which you can use like this (note that you can handle non-200 responses using any of the standard approaches for dealing with failed futures):

```
import dispatch._
import org.json4s._, org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }

val page = url("http://graph.facebook.com/9098498615")
val response = Http(page OK dispatch.as.json4s.Json)

response onComplete {
  case Success(json) => println(json \ "likes")
  case Failure(error) => println(error)
}
```

This example uses the [Json4s library](https://github.com/json4s/json4s), and similar support is provided for [Lift JSON](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/tree/master/liftjson) (but unfortunately nothing for [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/), although it's not too hard to write such a thing yourself).

Comment: I always get `object json4s is not a member of package dispatch.as`. Edit: Just realized I had to add the dependency to my build.sbt http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.databinder.dispatch/dispatch-json4s-native_2.10/0.11.1

Comment: @joslinm would you mind being more precise as to what you added to your build.sbt? I had the same problem, added the dependency but still having the issue.

Comment: `"net.databinder.dispatch" % "dispatch-json4s-native_2.11" % "0.11.1"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ur own favorite json-library (e.g. the play-framework-json-lib) like this:

```
val response = Http(requestUrl OK CarJsonDeserializer)
```

U have just to extend the (Response => Car) trait by the JsonDeserializer.

```
object CarJsonDeserializer extends (Response => Car) {
  override def apply(r: Response): Car = {
    (dispatch.as.String andThen (jsonString => parse(jsonString)))(r)
  }
}
```

and the json-parser:

```
implicit val carReader: Reads[Car] = (
  (JsPath \ "color").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "model").read[String]
)(Monitor.apply _)

private def parse(jsonString: String) = {
  val jsonJsValue = Json.parse(jsonString)
  jsonJsValue.as[Car]
}
```

See this blog post about this: https://habashics.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/parsing-json-play-lib-with-dispatch/